# Can't connect Nexus S to my Mac OS x Lion 10.7 for USB Debugging

Tags: android, usb, osx-lion, macos, nexus-s

I tried to connect my Nexus S (Android version 2.3.5) to my macbook pro 10.7 (OSX Lion). However, the notification on android phone was just ON and OFF alternative. I tried this command on my terminal.

```
adb usb 
>>error: device not found
adb devices 
>>List of devices attached 
>>[ nothing here ]
```

Please help me with this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you don't have a power-only USB cable. If the phone charges but Mac doesn't think it's there, it's a sure sign.

Comment: OSX was not recognizing my device at all and it was driving my crazy. it never occurred to me that there were different types of cables that would prevent this. This was my issue, and swapping the cable out fixed the problem immediately. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Also, if that does not work, check to see if the device shows up under USB in the System Profiler (included in OS X). If it is showing up there, but not in ADB, try adding the USB Vendor ID of the phone to ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

This file can be created if it does not already exist. The Vendor ID of the Nexus S is 0x18d1.  Please make sure the last line of the file is a Vendor ID, do not leave a blank line at the end.

Comment: Wish I could give you a bunch of upvotes, the Vendor ID was the only thing that fixed my issue.

Comment: where do I change the vender id in my Samsung Nexus S device?

Answer (score 1):

It seams that there are some problems with debugging an Android device on OS X (most describe this problem after updating to Lion).

There are some threads/discussions which offer a few possible workarounds, see if one of them works for you:

- [OS X 10.6.6 and "adb devices" fails to list android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680637/mac-os-x-10-6-6-and-adb-devices-fails-to-list-android-devices)
- [The Issue on the Google Bug-Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15583)

Although, this seams to be a problem on Google / Apples site so you can only check if you can work it around.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with my N-06C which is made by NEC and solve by writing code less kext.

http://8kpxen.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-adb-to-your-android-device-on.html

Please read this blog and download kext.
Since this kext file is configured for N-06C, please modify for your environment.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, checked ADB in Eclipse, and was able to select and push file to device. Pushed APK and installed.

I know, horrible solution but Lion has been a nightmare for most developers. Hopefully the updates keep comin!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue.  I can issue commands via ./adb shell  like ls, but not push and pull, and when i do ./adb devices, it shows my device id, but when i start an interactive shell, adb devices shows nothing.  i can still list files in the interactive shell, but still no push or pull.