# DDMS/ADB Not Detecting Device After Recent Update

Tags: android, device, adb, ddms

I have very little information about what I might have done wrong but my DDMS and ADB have suddenly stopped detecting any Android device that I plug into my MacBook Air running Mac OS 10.7.4. I believe this started happening after a recent update I ran from Eclipse Indigo to update the Android SDK and API. Everything on my phone is as it should be (debugging is on, allow apps to install from unknown sources is enabled, ect.). I'm wondering if anyone else has been experiencing this problem recently and knows how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out that this didn't have anything to do with a recent update. In fact, it was because I installed EasyTether and apparently it interferes with the ADB. I found my answer here: [OS X 10.6.6 and "adb devices" fails to list android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680637/mac-os-x-10-6-6-and-adb-devices-fails-to-list-android-devices).