# Android Studio cannot find Samsung device on my Mac but works in PC

Tags: android, macos, adb, driver

I recently got a replacement of Samsung Galaxy Note 3 with Lollipop (stock rom, no root). I used to use this device with rooted version and it worked perfectly with my Android Studio on my OSX 10.10.5 Yosemite.

Now, with a new phone, it doesn't want to connect.

What I have done:

1. Installed/re-installed Samsung Kies3 OR Android Data Transfer that was provided from Google many many times. (Interestingly, data transfer works just fine.)
2. Reinstalled adb drivers using this [adb not finding my device / phone (MacOS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x)
   -> What's funny is, in my System Information, it says SAMSUNG_Android instead of Unkown device.
3. Disabled/Enabled developer mode & USB Debugging
4. Restarted the phone
5. Changed the cables, Used/Not used usb hubs.
6. Tried on PC (Windows 10, Android Studio). WORKS LIKE A BOSS.

The problem I'm guessing

I think the phone fails at registering my Macbook Pro as a trusted device because every single time I connect to my Macbook Pro, it would ask if I want to allow USB debugging on this device. (Yes I check "always allow on this device" every time it is asked. I tried to revoke  USB debugging authorizations, too)

Has anyone have the same problem? I really need to work on my laptop because I'd have to go somewhere out of town where I can't be in front of my PC.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Try to set google drivers for your device in device manager.

Comment: How? I thought Google drivers are only for Windows. The link Google Developer provides only has download for Windows.

Comment: I don't think this is to helpful but I am using the exact same setup as you and it worked without any problems for me. Did you try "adb devices" from command line to see if you see the device. One problem I have had is running VMWare and it takes the device instead of OSX. Are you running VMWare?

Comment: I made sure I turned off any running VMWares. I recently installed Ubuntu on my macbook and it's working perfectly fine. However, OSX would still not recognize my device. It's very, very strange. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking and looking, I finally found a solution.

It was because of EasyTether I installed on OSX and my phone.

Using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680637/os-x-10-6-6-and-adb-devices-fails-to-list-android-devices), I solved the issue.

Only problem was I could not unload the kext so I just removed it and restarted the OSX. Finally device showing up on ADB.

### **EDIT**: copying and pasting the *this solution* part to save an extra click

If you have installed EasyTether on OS X, the EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext can prevent adb from communicating with your mobile device.

If you use Easy Tether, BEFORE you plug in your phone run:

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext
```

(or unplug/plug your phone in after)

If you are done debugging and want to use EasyTether again, either restart or:

```
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext
```

If you want to remove the EasyTether kext so it never hassels you again:

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext
```

Reference/Credit: http://www.intohand.com/post.php?s=2011-02-17-android-debug-bridge-not-just-working-on-mac